# What's the lower limit for energy usage to desalinate water?

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider a desalination process where you enter sea water and receive fresh water and brine (or maybe pure salt).

How do I compute the least amount of energy per mass? I think this has something to do with the entropy of the different mixtures, mostly dependent on the salt concentration in the brine. 
Is this correct? How to calculate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the process is done at constant temperature and pressure, what you want is the Gibbs free energy difference.  The reaction could be taken to be 1 mole of water in brine on one side and one mole of pure water on the other side.

The result should be a positive number since the process is not spontaneous.  However the value of $\Delta G$ will be the minimum non-mechanical work necessary for the process.

To understand this read up on the Gibbs free energy.